# Should I have my web pages reference a copy of jquery.js on my own server or from the code.jquery.com?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to javascript etc so may be this is dumb question.
I was looking into JQuery-UI tutorials and they have:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>     
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />    
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>    
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

If I can include js code like this, why would I ever need to download the jquery library?

Comment: save that js file and use in your site or wherever you want

Comment: @QWR:Actually the tutorial has:`<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />  
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>  
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>`. You mean download all files?

Comment: Better use googleapis.com link as stated in answers, because it should be faster and some visitors can have it already in cache from another website which use it, so it will load faster.

Comment: @MahmoudFarahat:You mean you guys writing in jquery never download it? You use urls?

Comment: @Jim yes , it's better to use online version as it's always up to date

Comment: MahmoudFarahat - No I wouldn't do that. You'll find that one day your site breaks because jQuery updated and deprecated some of the functionality you're using in your scripts. Always use a specific version rather than the *"latest"*

Comment: @Jim : I answered as how the question was given . well it is not cumbersome task to download them . for example in asp.net mvc u can use nuget-package and bundle to batch them in one js foro CDN

Comment: _"You mean you guys writing in jquery never download it?"_ - Well if you're interested in having a look at the source to see how it's implemented you'd need to download it, even if you only ever view it in your browser... Is your real question "Should I have my web pages reference a copy of jquery.js on my own server or from the code.jquery.com site?"

Comment: @nnnnnn:I guess that is my core issue.

Answer (score 14):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
if (!window.jQuery) {
    document.write('<script src="/path/to/your/jquery"><\/script>');
}
</script>
```

When you use a CDN, the users don't have to download the jquery file again as they most probably already have it cached.

The code in second script tag checks if the jquery was available from CDN or not, and falls back to local copy of jquery on your machine.

Comment: Maybe important for TS who is new to jQuery: this means that you DO have to download jQuery and upload it to your web space!

Answer (score 5):

If you wanted to work locally, it's better to have a local copy.

What you're looking at is called a CDN - a Content Delivery Network. It's beneficial because it allows potential caching of the resource across multiple websites, as well as not counting towards your same-network limit imposed by the browser.

The HTML5 Boilerplate does it a bit differently:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

As you can see, we're using a protocol-relative path, so if you were to look at your work locally (without running a local server), your browser would hang while it tried to find the resource on the `file://` protocol. Another good reason to have a local copy.

Comment: So `http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js` is guaranteed to always exist?

Comment: Yes @QWR.Just use it. Not reated to performance if this is what you mean with profile.

Comment: @Jim - Yes it (pretty much) is. I added the HTML5 Boilerplate version above. They use the google CDN. They also have a fallback just incase it doesn't exist.

Comment: It's not really "guaranteed" to exist, because you have no control over the server. The only way to be sure is have your own copy of it.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on your project setup and requirements. From my experience I have found the following reasons to download 3rd party js libraries, that are otherwise publicly available:

- **Intranet Systems.** If the application is an intranet system that has no access the to outside world, then a local copy is a must
- **Restricted Hosting Environment.** If for some reason the hosting environment cannot access certain adresses with resources for the app, or is explicitly configured not to, then local copies are the way to go
- **Performance.** If the connection to the original library url is slow, and caching is not enabled on the clients (a rare or very specific case), perhaps the application would need to maintain its own copy

A different approach is to have a content delivery network (CDN) that is set up in a way to specifically serve your application with resources. Then, it is the CDN's responsibility to use the most appropriate way of fetching the resources. The application only needs to have access to the CDN. This is a preferred solution for many systems as the content management is decoupled from the application and also because CDN-s perform better with most browsers.

Comment: You mean you guys writing in jquery never download it? You use urls?

Comment: The tutorial also has `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" /`. This is expected to be local

Comment: @Jim, the stylesheet url is probably local in order to have the tutorial ran locally. Or may be because no one thought the tutorial urls should be consistent. In a production application, the decision for using exernal or internal urls is a matter of developer decision and circumstantial limitations.