# Webpage tabs not loaded properly, if router is disconnected from outside world?

Tags: jquery, html

I have an embedded webserver that I created a website html page for it.  If I 
disconnect our router from the outside world, and I try to access the page, it 
loads with the tabs showing like links and the tables from each tab placed one 
on top of the other.

I am taking this embedded webserver on a show, were I don't have access to the
web or internet access, if anyone has seen this problem before can you explain
what could be happening?

Comment: Are you loading jquery or jquery-ui from a cdn?

Comment: Also, is this going through a webserver or did you just open the html file directly in the browser?

Comment: Please also post any errors in the javascript console.

Comment: Jason P - I think you and user2959229 are onto something...

Comment: I have the following script jQuery line: <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />   I also have this line script:   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>  Do you believe that is causing the issue?

Comment: I found this on StackOverFlow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16507155/should-i-have-my-web-pages-reference-a-copy-of-jquery-js-on-my-own-server-or-fro  I think if I download the CDN stuff to my laptop, it will load properly, does anyone agree this would be a solution?

Comment: Yes that would cause the issue.  Everything must be on your computer, nothing can be loaded from the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that all linked script and image resources are being served from your own server. Any reliance on externally hosted resources will cause failures when there is no connection to the Internet.

Comment: I think your on to something here user2959229.